# pyAudio starts streaming before start_stream is called

Tags: python, callback, stream, pyaudio

I want to use pyAudio in the callback mode and prepare a stream with `stream = pyaudio.PyAudio().open(...)`. I expect my `callback` method to be called after I start the stream with `stream.start_stream()`. However, my callback function is called immediately after I create the stream object (see demo code).

Am I using pyAudio wrong or is this a bug?

```
import time
import pyaudio

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    print("CALLBACK")
    return (in_data, pyaudio.paContinue)

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(2), channels=1, rate=44100, 
                input=True, output=False, stream_callback=callback,
                frames_per_buffer=5000)

# XXX: Note that I do not call stream.start_stream() here

time.sleep(5)

stream.close()
```

I am using python 3.6.5 and pyaudio 0.2.11 and portaudio 19.6.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initializer for a `pyaudio.Stream` (which `open` initializes) starts the stream by default. If you didn't want it started with `PyAudio.open`, you can pass `start=False`.

Excerpt from [the documentation](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#pyaudio.Stream.__init__) (*emphasis mine*):

> `__init__(PA_manager, rate, channels, ... , start=True, ...)`
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> ...
>
> - `start` – Start the stream running immediately. **Defaults to `True`. In general, there is no reason to set this to False.**

Comment: Odd comment.  The reason to set it to False is when you need to separate the load step from the play step.